# RAID Configuration 'seen' through

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, ssd, raid

I have a RAID0 (striped) configuration with the following:

- 64GB SSD
- 128GB SSD
- 640GB HDD

I'm turning my PC into a hackintosh, and the installer loaded properly, BUT

**The installer saw the individual disks, along with their old partitions that were on them before the RAID array was created(!!).**

What's going on here? I thought a RAID0 configuration was seen properly, regardless the OS.
I checked in Linux, and it saw the RAID0 configuration as it was meant to be seen. The Windows 7 installer doesn't see anything until I manually install the Nivida SATA RAID drivers.

How is this happening (I believe it's got absolutely nothing to do with the fact that it's a hackintosh)?

I'm using [the Asrock N68C-GS FX motherboard](http://www.asrock.com/mb/NVIDIA/N68C-GS%20FX/), and the RAID array was created with the motherboard's onboard RAID controller's management system.

Comment: How did you create the RAID array?

Comment: Also, I wouldn't recommend mixing classes of storage devices (SSDs and HDDs, HDDs of various rotation speeds, etc.) within a single RAID array; it's likely to lead to unpredictable performance.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling The RAID array was created using my BIOS's RAID menu; I remember it specifically telling me that 'all data on affected disks will be erased'.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include additional information in response to requests in comments. Also, please at a minimum include the exact make and model of your motherboard, and BIOS version number if possible.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Info added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's going on here? I thought a RAID0 configuration was seen properly, regardless the OS.

This only occurs if you have true, independent hardware RAID with it's own microcontroller or CPU (like an Adaptec RAID PCI card) and not firmware-assisted "fake" RAID that's prevalent on modern systems.

---

SATA RAID cards aren't terribly expensive these days and will provide better performance than fake motherboard RAID.  Also @Michael Kjörling's advice about not mixing SSD/HDD on the same RAID set should be taken.  At the very least you are not getting all the write performance out of your SSD you can be, the RAID's write performance would be hamstrung by the slowest drive.

Comment: The motherboard has it's own independent Marvell RAID controller, and not so-called 'firmware-assisted' RAID. I have another question related to this, but it'll be better asking a new question on it.

Answer (score 1):

It has everything to do with the fact that it's a hackintosh. The installer doesn't support your firmware, it's really that simple. You created software 'fakeraid' using your BIOS, and the installer doesn't support it. So it looks at the raw disks.

It's not unusual for RAID controllers to ignore some parts of the disk, apparently in this case the partition tables. So you still see the old partition tables when the RAID is ignored.

Comment: I'm confused, I never created any 'fakeraid software', the RAID 'software' is in fact a physical Marvell RAID controller on the motherboard.

Comment: @zyboxenterprises You did. The "Marvell RAID controller" is a controller that can run RAID software and perhaps has some hardware that slightly accelerates some RAID operations but maybe not.