# Do SSDs have to have AHCI to maximize performance?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard, raid, sata

After my [last post concerning my motherboard's RAID](https://superuser.com/questions/757651/raid-configuration-seen-through), I'm considering purchasing an additional dedicated RAID controller, but I have a few concerns about what to buy, because I'm facing yet another issue.

My [ASRock N68C-GS FX motherboard](http://www.asrock.com/mb/NVIDIA/N68C-GS%20FX/) only seems to have IDE and RAID options for the drives, and no SATA AHCI option.
I have a single 640GB HDD, and the other two drives I have are SSDs (excluding my DVD drive).

My question is, does AHCI increase the performance of SSDs, as opposed to IDE? If this is true, am I currently experiencing degraded performance from my SSDs as a result of this?

If so, are there PCI SATA controllers available that support AHCI?

Speed is more important to me than having a RAID0 Striped configuration, which is why I need to decide whether to get a new PCI RAID card, or a PCI AHCI SATA card.

Comment: To answer one of the questions: Yes, AHCI will allow you to hit ~500 MBps read/write and IDE mode will limit you to ~250